# Autoscaling WebSocket connections in nginx

Tags: nginx, websocket, autoscaling

I need some suggestions to setup auto-scaling, in nginx, of websocket connections.  Let's say I have nginx configured to proxy websocket connections to 4 upstream backend servers. When I try to add a 5th server to the upstream block and reload nginx, I see that nginx keeps the existing worker processes running and additionally create new ones to serve new websocket connections. I guess the old workers remain until the earlier connections close.

Ideally, as we auto-scale, we want the number of nginx worker processes to remain the same. Is there a way to transfer the socket connections from the older worker processes to the newer worker processes?

thanks.

Comment: nginx doesn't need scaling, it works perfectly as it is. You will run out of bandwidth before you can even use one worker fully... and you won't have any benefit having more than 4 workers. As for your question, that's the intended behavior. Each worker will only be recycled when `worker_connections` is exceeded for that worker. This is to prevent re-spawning which is expensive.

Comment: @peixotorms I do not want to scale nginx, only the backend app server. However, I need to update the upstream block and reload nginx. When I do this, the nginx worker processes double - both the old and the new ones exist simultaneously - as the current websocket connections continue to remain active. Is there a way to avoid this and have fixed number of nginx workers even after reload?

Comment: OK, now I get it. What happens when you just do a stop on nginx, are those workers still running?

Comment: @peixotorms Those workers stop, but that will disconnect all the websocket connections which is not desirable.

Comment: @vrtx54234 did you end up finding a good solution for this?

Comment: @obviyus I did not look into this again.  Reading the problem statement, it feels like we need the reverse proxy to support dynamic upstream configuration.  I know envoyproxy supports this via CDS. For nginx, the plus version seems to support it. See https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/dynamic-configuration-api/